# How can i get multi thread parallel calculator (factorial sum)

Tags: java, multithreading, calculator

I will input some number to calculates sum of Factorial series,
like if i put 5, output will be 1!+2!+3!+4!+5!, but calculating processing could be heavy so i want to use multiple treads that calculates each factorial.. means thread1 cals 1!, thread2 cals 2!...
i used arrays of threads but can't sync them in propel results. and can't find the way to sum these results.

i wrote codes...

```
public class Calthread extends Thread{
    private int num=1;
    public Calthread(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public void run() {
        int dft = 1;
        for(int i=1; i<=num; i++) {
            dft = dft*i;
        }
        System.out.println(num + "! result :" + dft);
    }

}
```

this is for 1 thread

for main class

```
public class calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("input number>>");
        int k = scanner.nextInt();  //input 'k'

        int sum = 0;

        Calthread[] cal = new Calthread[k]; // make threads number of 'k'
        for(int i = 0; i<k; i++) {
            cal[i] = new Calthread(i+1);
            cal[i].start();
        }
    }

}
```

how can I Sync them and print the sum of all?

Comment: It seems you're interested in multithread, but if your goal is to speed things up, don't you want to use the fact that when computing 5!, you had to compute all lower factorials? Or that 1!+2!+3!+4!+... = 2*(1+3*(1+4*(1+...))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return value from thread you should use `Callable` instead of `Runnable`:

```
public class Calthread implements Callable<Integer> {

    private int num = 1;

    public Calthread(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() {
        int dft = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
            dft = dft * i;
        }
        return dft;
    }
}
```

And in the main class:

```
public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("input number>>");
        int k = scanner.nextInt();  //input 'k'

        int sum = 0;
        // Make threads number of 'k'. Here we use List instead of array because there is such contract in ExecutorService
        List<Calthread> cal = new ArrayList<>(k);
        // Create thread pool with fixed number of threads
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(k);
        // Add all Callable task in one collection
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            cal.add(new Calthread(i+1));
        }
        try {
            // Invoke all Callable task and get List with results
            List<Future<Integer>> results = service.invokeAll(cal);
            // Future::get is blocking method. It waits result.
            for (Future<Integer> result : results) {
                sum += result.get();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Result: " + sum);
        // We need to shutdown our service
        service.shutdown();
    }
}
```